# NoneType in MU5 on BBC Microbit

Tags: bbc-microbit

I have some code for a simple rev counter on the Microbit. When returning the variable rev_per_second, sometimes it is a NoneType (for reasons unknown).  I try to trap this within the function, but it doesn't seem to work. Where am I going wrong please.

```
# part of the function revs()  

     if end_time < running_time():   
         try:
             rev_per_second = rev_per_second
         except TypeError:
             rev_per_second = 1    
         return rev_per_second  # make this value available to the main program

# main part of the program            
while True:
    rev_per_min = revs() # sometimes this is "None" Why??
    display.scroll(str(rev_per_min))
```

Comment: There is not enough context here to be sure, but most likely, something is initialising or re-setting `revs_per_second` to "None".

Comment: rev_per_second is set to 1 at the top of the function before the while statement, so what could set it to None ?

Comment: Reduce your code to a minimal reproducible example, or link to the full code on github. We can't guess the answer.

Comment: sorry, I had to reject your edit to my answer - you should either comment on my answer, or up-vote it (assuming, as I interpret, it helped). You can also either answer the question yourself, or edit the question to make it clearer. Sorry if it seems a bit convoluted, the idea is to generate a searchable resource of useful Q&A. Also, for reference, you might need to @ mention other users if you want them to see your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is almost certainly that there is a path through the function that does not end in a return statement, so Python by default returns None.

Check that all paths from your revs() function end at a `return` statement, otherwise Python will return `None` if there is no return statement.

Comment: Found the elusive answer. It was an indentation error on the return from a function.

Comment: Looks like I upset someone :)